# User selects emailProvider, but program won't define the variable

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, break, continue

I'm writing my first Python program from scratch; it writes and sends an email based on user input for each variable. The first variable to define is the user's email server, which reads like this:

```
# Establish email server connection
print('Welcome to Brett\'s email program! Let\'s send a message.')
emailServer = input('First, I need your email provider: Gmail, Yahoo, or Outlook?\n')
```

The user enters their email provider, which should then name the variable from this list:

```
if emailServer == 'Gmail':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.gmail.com'
if emailServer == 'Yahoo!':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
if emailServer == 'Yahoo':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
if emailServer == 'Outlook':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.office365.com' # Found this server name on serversmtp.com
# TODO: Test other email providers (iCloud, AT&T, Comcast, Verizon)
else:
    print('I don\'t know that email provider. Please try again.')
```

Every time I run the program in this instance, I get the else statement ('I don't know that email provider.'), and the program goes on to ask for the email address.

I've tried a couple different methods for handling these if/else statements. I've done elif statements, continue statements, break statements, and even a Boolean statement like this one:

```
if emailServer == 'Gmail' = True:
        emailProvider = 'smtp.gmail.com'
```

None of them work. The program does work if I make Gmail the default value for emailProvider, so I know this is the bug section.

How do I make this section work? I think that putting the email provider info in a dictionary might do the trick, but I don't know how to implement that. I'm still learning as a developer, so giving an example of how the code would be organized (dictionary entry, proper elif statement) goes a long way towards comprehension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if... elif... else...`:

```
print('Welcome to Brett\'s email program! Let\'s send a message.')
emailServer = input('First, I need your email provider: Gmail, Yahoo, or Outlook?\n')

if emailServer == 'Gmail':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.gmail.com'
elif emailServer == 'Yahoo!':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
elif emailServer == 'Yahoo':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
elif emailServer == 'Outlook':
    emailProvider = 'smtp.office365.com'
else:
    print('I don't know that email provider. Please try again.')
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. The Yahoo! option throws these messages:

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 631, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 421, in docmd
    return self.getreply()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")

smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Ismail. That fix allows the Gmail option to work properly and proceed through the program. I did get this message block when I used Yahoo! as the emailProvider:

```
File "/home/pi/mu_code/emailSenderTest/emailSenderTest.py", line 56, in <module>
    conn.login(userName, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 631, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 421, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Anyone have an idea on what this means or how to make the Yahoo! function work. My port is set at 587.

Comment: I might be wrong, but `587` is the port for Gmail. According to my searches the port for Yahoo is `465`.